# Image upload returns 500 (Something went wrong. Looks like server failed to load your request) in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Uploading always returns 500 Error everytime I upload an image. It is working on localhost but it is not working on prod. Below is my Form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('users.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="name">{{__('Name')}}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="{{__('Name')}}" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="logo">{{__('Logo')}} </label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="file" id="logo" name="logo" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-purple" type="submit">{{__('Save')}}</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

and here is my Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $users= new User;
    $users->name = $request->name;

    if($request->hasFile('logo')){
        $users->logo = $request->file('logo')->store('uploads/users');
    }

    if($users->save()){
        return redirect()->route('users.index');
    }
    else{

        return back();
    }
}
```

and here is my filesystem.php

```
 'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),


'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path(),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ]

],
```

I also check the logs and it has this error:

```
[2019-12-04 09:31:42] local.ERROR: Unable to guess the MIME type as no guessers are available (have you enable the php_fileinfo extension?). {"userId":9,"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Mime\\Exception\\LogicException(code: 0): Unable to guess the MIME type as no guessers are available (have you enable the php_fileinfo extension?). [stacktrace].
```

Note: My php_fileinfo extension is enabled.

I'll be waiting for solutions. Thank you :D

I also wanted to add that I deployed it Using IIS

Comment: why not check the logs so you can see why its returning a 500 status code

Comment: did you create `symlink` on server?

Comment: Permissions for the folder maybe?

Comment: I checked the logs on my project folder and it has this log and I don't know what it means. 

[2019-12-04 09:31:42] production.ERROR: Unable to guess the MIME type as no guessers are available (have you enable the php_fileinfo extension?). {"userId":9,"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Mime\\Exception\\LogicException(code: 0): Unable to guess the MIME type as no guessers are available (have you enable the php_fileinfo extension?).
[stacktrace]

Comment: have you enabled the php_fileinfo extension? please add the error message to you question by editing your question, thanks

Comment: Yes I checked and it is enabled.

Comment: how did you check it was enabled btw? as there are multiple different php configurations

Comment: I checked it using this post on 
https://community.xibo.org.uk/t/how-do-i-enable-fileinfo-in-php/78